# Display ratio two columns from MySQL in web page

Tags: php, html, mysql, pivot-table

I have two tables in MySQL with values A (db_bird) and B (db_disability). I try to draw from them how many times the value B (disability) occurred at the A value (in a bird).

Where should I start?
I do not care about dynamic sorting, buttons, etc. A simple table with a result.

Below is a graphic example of what I mean:

[image: Graphic example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You potentially have two tasks here:

First Aggregate:

```
SELECT db_bird       AS Bird,
       db_disability AS Disibility,
       COUNT(*)      AS ct
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY db_bird, db_disability;
```

This gives you

```
Bird    Disability  ct
Crow    broken wing 2
Crow    broken leg  1
Raven   broken leg  1
Seagull broken leg  1
```

If you are happy with that, you might want to stop there.

If you continue, you are asking for an arbitrary number of columns, and some messy SQL.  Read Q&A on [pivot-table] [mysql] for lots of discussion of how to do this step.